# Add Criteria To VBA Code and Requery

Tags: ms-access, vba, criteria, ms-access-2010

So the following VBA code I have will requery the form based on the Combo1 value equal to January. Eventually, I'll have X number of years in the Combo value and only want to display all records based on each year.

Is it possible to add additional VBA code to use the Criteria from the query instead of having X amount of queries and requery them based on the year.

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()

If Combo1.Value = "2013" Then
[Form_Main Form].RecordSource = "Main_Form_Query"
[Form_Main Form].Requery
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: insted of writing the name of your query in the `RecordSource` property, you can create the SQL statement in runtime, and pass it to this property

Comment: Can it be done within VBA? Only reason I ask is I'm not too familar with the suggestion you are reffering to.

Comment: I've posted an answer to ilustrate my suggestion. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct the query in runtime (remember: a query object in access is just an sql statement)

So, let's asume that your data is stored in a table called `tblMyData` that has columns called `month` (String, month name) and `year` (Numeric, Integer) (*just examples*). You can generate the SQL query in VBA this way:

```
...
Dim strSQL as String
...
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMyData " & _
         "WHERE month='" & ComboMonth.Value & "' " & _
         "  AND year=" & ComboYear.Value ";"
...
[Form_Main Form].RecordSource = strSQL
[Form_Main Form].Requery
...
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Note changing the RecordSource property automatically triggers requery.  You don't need to call `.Requery` again.

Comment: @HansUp Didn't remembered that :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Open the form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) in a different way.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm",,,"MyYear=2013"
```

Or

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm",,,"MyYear=" & Me.MyCombo
```

Assuming that MyYear in the table or query is numeric. If it is not, you can use single quotes.

The general idea is that you use a form with all records, and use the Where argument of OpenForm to specify the records that should be shown. You can do the same with reports.

Answer (score 1):

I have only a vague idea about what you're trying to accomplish.  It might help to show us the SQL from `Main_Form_Query`.  Meanwhile, consider whether you can use the form's `.Filter` property to do what you need.

If the form's Record Source includes a text field named `fiscal_year`, you could filter the rows displayed based on the year selected in your combo box.

```vb
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()
    ' .Value is the default property, so not required after Me.Combo
    Me.Filter = "fiscal_year = '" & Me.Combo1 &  "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Yet another approach could be to reference the combo value in `Main_Form_Query`.

```sql
WHERE
       Forms!YourForm!Combo1 Is Null
    OR some_field = Forms!YourForm!Combo1
```

Then do `Me.Requery` in the combo's After Update event.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the OP prevents the use of any user filters on the form? If so, how?